# using a string in php into a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, string

I am getting a string using PHP and then trying to put it into my database(mySql).  I keep getting an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'material )' at line 1.

Here is my code.  I printed out the statement in php and that is correct.

```
$description=$_POST["textField4"];

$description= addslashes($description);//found these two line using google
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);//neither seem to help.


$sql="INSERT INTO budget8000 (categories,subCategory, amount, date, description)
VALUES ($category,$subCategory, $amount, curdate(), $description )";
```

Comment: @sdleidhssirhc, you don't have to, but it's a SQL-injection hole if you don't!

Comment: What's the string you are giving?

Comment: I tried putting quotes around $description, it didn't work

Comment: The string is "Testing stuff".  I used an echo to print it out and it prints out ok

Comment: Which of the variables ($category, $subCategory, $description) contains word "material" when the error happens?

Comment: From the error message the problem seems to be "material )"... it looks like you haven't quoted / escaped it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is:

```
$description=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["textField4"]);
...
//and so on for each an every field that you $_GET or $_POST.

$sql= "INSERT INTO budget8000 (categories,subCategory, amount, date, description)
VALUES ('$category','$subCategory', '$amount', curdate(), '$description' )";
//      ^         ^ these quotes are vital to prevent SQL-injection and errors.
// without them mysql_real_escape_string will not work!
```

See: [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)

Comment: As a matter of fact, it's part of SQL syntax. So, these quotes vital to prevent syntax errors, not injections.

Comment: @Col, welcome back; as always you are correct, But I find it easier to remember that it is to prevent SQL-injection AND errors, because without the quotes the code **may** work, but you can be 100% sure that you are at risk of SQL-injection pwn-age.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the php function mysql_real_escape_string()

$description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);

[PHP documention for mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: the OP has already done, that. But using mres is not enough, you need to ALSO quote all the injected vars.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but that's exactly why. You did not answer the question, the OP already uses mysql_real_escape_string (incorrectly, but that's beside the point), and the error is not caused by mres. It is caused by not quoting the injected vars.